# Method Not Allowed Http Exception laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

Getting error in laravel simple controller class with following code

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use app\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class ProfileController extends Controller
{


    private $userId;

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->userId = Auth::id();    
    }

}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('user_profile','ProfileController@insert');
```

Calling by:   `<form action="/user_profile" method="post">`

Comment: share complete error.... also share the route details.

Comment: its complete, nothing else

Comment: which method?  GET? POST? PUT/PATCH? DELETE? We need INFORMATION, information, information...

Comment: please edit your question to include the route definition and the bit of code where you actually use the route in question that triggers the error

Comment: So you get error after submit the form? @VeeZPhone

Comment: yes when I submit it throws error

Comment: Do you have an insert method defined on that controller? because that's where your route is pointing.

Answer (score 0):

I have to run

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your ./routes/web.php file, and make sure that you're using the correct http method (get, post, put, delete)

When I got the error, I had this:

```
Route::post('/application/create', 'ApplicationsController@create');
```

Changing it to this, corrected the error:

```
Route::get('/application/create', 'ApplicationsController@create');
```